# What are these round bead like structures from Aloe Vera plant?

Tags: houseplants, aloe

I found these beads in the soil. I am intrigued to find out what these are.

[image: Aloe vera beads with the plant]

Comment: Intriguing. Those seems too small and round to be aloe vera fruits. [This paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/290456184_Morphological_and_Genetic_Characterization_of_Micropropagated_Field_Grown_Plants_of_Aloe_vera_L/figures?lo=1) depicts the structure of fruits and seeds of an aloe vera species. The fruits are usually bigger and more elongated compared to what you have shown. Or, are there species of aloe vera with such fruits?